# How to Sort Nova Metrics Results?

Tags: laravel-nova

```
class PartViews extends Partition
{
    /**
     * Calculate the value of the metric.
     *
     * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest  $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function calculate(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        return $this->sum($request, Record::class,'views', 'platform');
    }
    ...

}
```

In my Metrics, i Use sum to calculate items count, but due to i have more than one platform, my sum result has many.

But the Sum Result is Alphabetical, How can i make it ordered by sum

for example, default is sorted by alphabetical, I want to sorted it by sum result, and tell me which is the best choice.

So, What should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to sort by model, but I'm not sure what works:

```
public function calculate(NovaRequest $request)
    {
        return $this->sum($request, Record::orderBy('name'),'views', 'platform');
    }
```

Or you can transfer your own data:

```
@return \Laravel\Nova\Metrics\PartitionResult
```